# Get the SQL Server version to a variable in bash script

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I want to get the SQL Server version into a variable in my bash script.

I tried using

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q 'select @@VERSION'
```

but it returns a string containing a bunch of other information too - eg: the copyright information, 86/x64? etc.

What is the correct way to get just the version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you mean by 'SQL Server Version', but if you mean the build number:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128))"
```

Example output:

```
13.0.5081.1
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I was expecting, but now I am running into a weird issue when I try to execute your command as it is, I get the following error: "
Invalid column name 'ProductVersion'." , but when I just do 'sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA' and then type in ''SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128))' inside the sqlcmd command line it works. Not sure why this is happening!

Comment: Updated: I changed the outer single quotes to double quotes above, and it runs successfully